# jsp form not getting submitted

Tags: javascript, jsp

what I am trying to do here is in the form if none of the field is entered then alert is shown  and if even one of the field is entered, the form is submitted.and i am using javascript to submit the form here is my form-

```
   <form  method="POST" name="report" id="reportbean">

        <div id="maindiv">
            <div align="center">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p id="Title">CHANDNA COLD STORAGE
                </p>
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;   </p>
            <p align="center" style="font-size: 20px; text-align: left;"> OCCUPANT    DETAILS:</p>
            <table width="770" height="97" cellpadding="10" >
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName"     placeholder="FIRSTNAME" value="${firstname}" onchange="stringCheck(this);"  /></td>

                    <td><input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" placeholder="LASTNAME" value="${lastname}" onchange="stringCheck(this);"  ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Village" id="Village" placeholder="VILLAGE" value="${village}" onchange="stringCheck(this);" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FatherName" id="FatherName" placeholder="FATHER'S NAME" value="${sonof}" onchange="stringCheck(this);" ></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="District" id="District" placeholder="DISTRICT" value="${district}" onchange="stringCheck(this);" ></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
           <div id="occupationlist" >
            <display:table name="List" export="true" class="displaytag"   sort="list"   >
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />

                <display:column  property="occid" title="ID" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="firstName" title="First Name" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="lastName" title="Last Name"   ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="sonOf" title="Father's Name"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="district" title="District"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="village" title="Village"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  title="Reservation Form">
                    <input type="button" id="reservationid" name="show reservation" onClick="javascript:toggle1();" value="show reservation det">
                </display:column>
                <display:column  title="Agreement Form">

                    <input type="button" id="agreementid" name="show agreement" onClick="javascript:toggle2();" value="show agreement det">
                </display:column>
            </display:table>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="reservationlist" style="display: none">
                <display:table name="List1" export="true" class="displaytag" sort="list"  >
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true"  />

                <display:column  property="resid" title="Reservation ID" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="date" title="Date" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="weight" title="Weight"   ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="bags" title="Bags"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="amount" title="Amount"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="advance" title="Advance"  ></display:column>

            </display:table>   
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div id="agreementlist" style="display: none" >
                <display:table name="List2" export="true" class="displaytag" sort="list" >
                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />

                <display:column  property="agreeNo" title="Agreement ID" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="date" title="Date" ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="weight" title="Weight"   ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="rate" title="Rate"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="bags" title="Bags"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="amount" title="Amount"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="advance" title="Advance"  ></display:column>
                <display:column  property="lotNo" title="Lot No"  ></display:column>


            </display:table>            
            </div>
            <p align="CENTER">
              <input type="button" name="BACK" id="BACK" value="BACK"  width="10px" height="10px" onClick="javascript:goBack()">&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="button" name="SUBMIT" id="submit" value="SEARCH" onclick="checkemptyreport();" >
            </p>

   </div>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

    </form>
```

and here is my javascript function -

```
  function checkemptyreport()
 {
var firstname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
var lastname = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
var fathername = document.getElementById("FatherName").value;
var village = document.getElementById("Village").value;
var district = document.getElementById("District").value;
if((firstname=="") && (lastname == "") && (village == "") && (fathername == "") &&     (district == "")  )
{

    alert("Enter Atleast One field");
    document.getElementById("FirstName").focus();
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert(2);

    //document.forms["report"].submit();
   document.form["report"].action = "/reportbeanservlet";
    //document.location = "reportbeanservlet";
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the type of the search button to "submit" (type button does not submit a form), and it will submit the form. Or you can do:

```
  document.form["report"].submit();
```

inside the `checkemptyreport()` function.

Comment: if i change the search button to submit after clicking on button it checks for validation and then automatically submits the form. i want if none of the field is entered. it shouldn't the form.

Comment: Isn't that what you're trying to accomplish, i.e. validate the inputs, and then submit?

Comment: @Divyang, if your form is not valid you just return false after showing your message. This will prevent the form to be posted.

Comment: if i change the search button to submit after clicking on button it checks for the fields and even if none of the field is entered ,it submits the form.which i dont want.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

**Javascript**:

```
window.onsubmit = function()
{
    var firstname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
    var district = document.getElementById("District").value;

    if(firstname == "" && lastname=="" && district=="")
    {
        alert("Fill in at least one");
        return false;
    }
    else  
    {
        alert(2);
        //document.forms["report"].submit();
        document.form["report"].action = "/reportbeanservlet";
        //document.location = "reportbeanservlet";
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Markup**:

```
<form  method="POST" name="report" id="reportbean">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
    <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" />
    <input type="text" name="District" id="District" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is of course a smaller version of your code, but as @tomor sugested, you can do it with a submit button, and capturate the `onsubmit` event of your form.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/xZEbH/