# JSP Form not submitting

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I have run into an interesting issue that I have never encountered before. I have a Struts Java application that follows MVC. On the JSP form, when the submit button is pressed, it should post to a servlet. However, the submit buttons are not working and the form does not post. If I manually type the url that the form should post to and press enter, the form posts successfully.

I am at a loss because because I have never run into this issue. None of the forms on my application will post so it's not exclusive to one page. I am using JDK1.6.0_43

What is even more troubling is we have a production system with this same code that is running perfectly. I have changed the JDK via the eclipse build path but without any success.

Kind Regards,

Comment: You need to post some code here if you want help with it. At least a cut-down version that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: take a look at this
[jsp form not getting submitted]


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976562/jsp-form-not-getting-submitted

Comment: @SteveK will do when I get to a spot that I can provide it. The reason I didn't post it before is my question was more of a "have you guys ever run into this situation before."

Comment: We're at a loss and unable to help too because we didn't get to see any code!

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here  <form id="validateForm" name="validateForm" method="post" action="<webbase:encodeUrl>forgotUserValidatePrep.sap</webbase:encodeUrl>">
                              <div class="mod-p-bottom">
                                 <div class="abled">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label><webbase:message key="page.label.customerID" resource="ccsu_forgotusername"/></label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" 
                                        maxlength="<%=ValidationFactory.getInstance().getCustomerValidator().getAllowedCustNumberLength() %>"  
                                        placeholder="" name="j_customerID" id="j_customerID" 
                                    <% if (validation != null && validation.getCustomerID()!= null && validation.getCustomerID().length() > 0){ %>
                                        value = <%= validation.getCustomerID() %>
                                    <% } else if(request.getAttribute("j_customerID") != null && request.getAttribute("j_customerID").toString().length() > 0){ %>
                                        value = <%= request.getAttribute("j_customerID") %>
                                    <% } %>

                                    />
                                    <%-- <span class="help-inline inputerrortext hide">*Required Field</span>--%>
                                </div>

                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <input type="submit" name="continueButton" id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" 
                                    value="<webbase:message key="button.continue" resource="ccsu_forgotusername"/>"/>


                                <input type="submit" name="cancelButton" id="cancel" class="btn" 
                                    value="<webbase:message key="button.cancel" resource="ccsu_forgotusername"/>"/>



                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <div style="font-size: 14px; color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;"><webbase:message key="page.billCaption" resource="ccsu_registration"/></div>
                                <img src="<%=ThemePath.getInstance().getThemePath(pageContext)%>img/exampleBillImage.png" class="img-responsive" />
                              </div>
                          </form>
```

The form posts to a servlet that sniffs out the .sap convention. Simply pressing submit has not effect but if I write out the url in the browser and press enter, it submits.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. Here are the steps that I completed to resolve the issue.

1. I had build the project from an existing .ear but because of some underlying dependency I was unable to deploy the new project to the Java server. I then built a new project from a .war file and inserted all of the necessary .jars, jsp, etc. Apparently the system did not like this either. This is when I noticed the submit button behavior.
2. I deleted the project and then rebuilt it using the .war file and generated the .ear file as well. I then took the application-j2ee-engine.xml file from the old .ear file and inserted it.
3. Deployed the changes and everything was business as usual.

I have never encountered behavior in a web application like this before. Super strange. But then again, it is SAP!

Answer (score -1):

in jsp ,form  action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/youservletnameonly"

Comment: thank you for the response. Unfortunately it's a no go.